# Oracle SQL - Maximum from two select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max, where-clause

I have two select statements that find the maximum salary for a specific role. 
Now I want to have the maximum of the two returns of those select statements.
Think about the following code:

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) 
  FROM TABLE1 
 WHERE ROLE = 'MANAGER'

SELECT MAX(SALARY) 
  FROM TABLE1 
 WHERE ROLE = 'DEVELOPER';
```

At the end I want the maximum of these two numbers.

How would I do all this in one query?

Have two selects for maximum, then compare those maximums and give the maximum of the two maximums?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since both selects read from the same table, you can do this:

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROLE = 'MANAGER' OR ROLE = 'DEVELOPER'
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want maximum from more job titles, add that job title in "IN"  array. No need to write one select statement for each job title.

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROLE IN ('MANAGER','DEVELOPER')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can figure out the max salary and the role having that salary like this.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT MAX(SALARY) MAXSALARY, ROLE
     FROM TABLE1
    WHERE ROLE IN ('MANAGER','DEVELOPER')
    GROUP BY ROLE
    ORDER BY MAX(SALARY)
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with just one select statement which varies on the role.

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROLE = 'MANAGER' OR ROLE = 'DEVELOPER'
```